# Python - Read numbers from external file

Tags: python, numpy

I have a input file with this format:

```
 Head    
 20 20 20 !Random text
 random lines
```

I want to read the values as 3 different variables 'a' 'b' 'c' and multiply a*b

I have the following code:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import fileinput

filename = 'file.txt'
#filename = sys.argv[-1]

data = np.genfromtxt(filename, skip_header=8, dtype=[('a',int),('b',int),

('c',int)])

result = a*b
```

but it is not working.

Comment: What is not working? Please list exactly the error.

Comment: It's not working is not a concise description of this problem. Did you get an error message? Then you should edit your question and include the full traceback. Did the output not meet your expectations? Then you should include the actual output.

Answer (score 1):

You must do it using numpy?
Otherwise this should work if the file looks always like this.

```
with open("file.txt") as file_handle:
    file_handle.readline() # skip the header
    values = file_handle.readline().split()

a = int(values[0])
b = int(values[1])

result = a * b
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the little different approach in one line

```
import re
from functools import reduce
print(reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,[list(map(int,re.findall(r'\d+',i)))[:2] for i in open('file.txt') if re.findall(r'\d+',i)][0]))
```

output:

```
400
```